# Counting integers $k$ such that $(k,n)=(k+1,n)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of integers for which $(k,n)=1$ and $(k+1,n)=1$. Then how do I show that $$f(n)=n\cdot \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)$$

I have no idea how to start

Comment: I think there need to be a condition about $k$, such as $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: how do you prove the close form of Eulero's phi? Same way

Answer (score 2):

First note that we have exactly $n$ pairs of consecutive integers, as the pair is determined by the first number. Now you can use the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

$$f(n) = N - \sum N(c_i) + \sum N(c_i,c_j) - ... \pm \sum N(c_i,c_j,...,c_k)$$

Where $c_i$ is the condition that one of the numbers in the pair $(k,k+1)$ is divisible $p_i$, a prime divisor of $n$. You can notice that $N(c_i,c_j,...c_k) = \frac{2^{k}n}{p_ip_j...p_k}$, as every integer is in $2$ pairs (we don't count $n+1$ and also we never remove pair $(1,2)$ due to $1$, so we can skip the boundary cases). So now substitute this and after a little bit of factorizing you have.

$$f(n) = n - \sum \frac{2n}{p_i} + \sum \frac{2^2n}{p_ip_j} - ... \pm \sum \frac{2^kn}{p_ip_j...p_k} = n \prod_{p \mid n}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove two things :

1) $f(n)$ is multiplicative, i.e. $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for $(m,n)=1$.

2) The formula holds for $n=p^{k}$.

For 1), let $M=\{0\leq a\leq m-1|(a,m)=(a+1,m)=1\},N=\{0\leq b\leq n-1|(b,n)=(b+1,n)=1\},K=\{0\leq c\leq mn-1|(c,mn)=(c+1,mn)=1\} $, then there exists bijection between $M\times N$ and $K$ by Chinese remainder theorem.

2) is easy, just count.